# Как создать анкорную ссылку в шаблоне компонента Битрикса?

Tags: html, битрикс

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, как верно оформить анкорную ссылку в шаблоне компонента Битрикса? 
Есть шаблон компонента и необходимо на всех страницах этого шаблона сделать, чтобы при клике на верхней части странице на иконку "Оставить комментарий", перекидывало на эту же страницу вниз к комментариям.

Поставила анкор в необходимом месте странице

```
<a id="add_comment"></a>
```

Но не могу понять, как оформить ссылку, чтобы она была корректна для любой страницы, собранной по этому шаблону. Попробовала такой вариант:

```
<a href="http://сайт.ru/articles/./../#add_comment" ><img src="../articles/peopls/knopka_share.png"></a>
```

Но при таком варианте идет переход на главную.

Так как же верно оформить ссылку в шаблоне Битрикса, чтобы она действовала на всех страницах articles ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решила таким образом.
Вызвала УРЛ текущей страницы + якорь

```
<a href="<?=$APPLICATION->GetCurPage();?>#reviews">Посмотреть отзывы</a>
```

И собственно сам "якорь" в нужном месте

```
<a id="reviews"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если у нас якорь и ссылка на одной странице

`<a href="#add_comment"></a>`

Если Нужно из списка перейти к комментариям статьи то ссылка будет примерно такая

`<a href="<?=$arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>#add_comment"></a>`

Comment: ни тот, ни другой вариант не работают :( Почему то ссылка переводит на главную страницу сайта, вместо нужного места на странице

Comment: @Alla слеша лишнего у Вас нет